# Winforms - Fill user control inside panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to winforms, what i am trying to do is a simple form:

- In my form there is a panel.
- The panel is linked to a user control
- The user control should fill the panel.

This is my form:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();

        panel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
        userControl.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)((((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom)
     | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right)));
        userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Not working -> the control doest stretch

[image: pic]

Comment: Why you doing this in code level?

Comment: I get the feeling that you meant to set the Dock property of the user control rather than the Panel.  What would be the point of setting the Anchor and Dock of the Panel and neither of the user control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();
        userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(userControl);

    }
```

`userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` should call before Add to panel1.

You also need to set `Anchor` property of controls inside UserControl to stretch it based on usercontrol stretch in panel.

Like.

```
Public Sub UserControl1()

        //This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
        Label2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
        Label4.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        Label3.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
    End Sub
```

**Note:** `userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` stretch only usercontrol it self not controls inside user control. To stretch controls of user control you need to set `Dock` as well as `Anchor` property accordingly.

Comment: not working. the control doesnt strech trough the panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to dock your user control as well. Docking panel makes it to dock to the form but not the `UserControl`.

```
userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: You need to dock the `panel1` as well as `userControl` not any one. you need to do that for **both**

Comment: docked both to fill, same result

Comment: @omriman12 Try removing `Anchor` property. Anchor is not required and see if that helps.